# EXECUTE AS/REVERT within a transaction in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, transactions

Some work being done with SQL Server requires that I switch which user we are executing as during a transaction from C# side.  I am wondering how transactions and context switches interact in SQL Server.

(pseudocode)

```
using(var transaction = database.GetTransaction())
{
    using(database.ExecuteAs("User A")) // EXECUTE AS User = "User A"
    {
        // Run queries as User A as part of the transaction
    } // REVERT
    using(database.ExecuteAs("User B")) // EXECUTE AS User = "User B"
    {
        // Run queries as User B as part of the transaction
    } // REVERT
    // Run queries as DBO as part of the transaction
    transaction.Commit();
}
```

I've looked at the documentation for EXECUTE AS and can't see any notes on whether transactions are honoured after switching user.  Does anyone know if they are?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Database transactions (SqlTransaction) are session-scoped rather than user-scoped so you can use `EXECUTE AS` and `REVERT` within the same transaction (and database connection).